# how to call the function using line edit pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here in my sample program i want to call a function using a line edit
here i set the text using leaser bar code scanner after set the text i want to call a function but i used here different types of signal slots 
cursorPositionChanged,editingFinished,inputRejected,returnPressed,selectionChanged,textChanged ,textEdited.No one is working perfectly.Can you please help me.Thank you in advance.

small piece of code:

```
self.produ_le.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.myfuncton)

def myfuncton(self):
        print "tryblockkkkk",InvItem,len(InvItem)
        self.w={}
        self.y=""

        self.product_varient=check_productverient(csrf,sess_id,InvItem['results'][0]['pk'])
        print self.product_varient,"*******************"

        if len(self.product_varient)>0:

            self.box.addWidget(self.invlabel)
            self.box.addWidget(self.produ_le)
            self.box.addWidget(self.qty_le)
            self.box.addWidget(self.cb)
            self.in_se_box.addWidget(self.create_btn)
            self.in_se_box.addWidget(self.close_btn)
            self.cellWidget4.setLayout(self.in_se_box)
```

Comment: here i am not editing the text not changing text by using leaser scanner i displaying the text in line edit after that i need to execute this function

Comment: returnPressed should work, provide a [mre]

Comment: sir return pressed  means after set the text i should press enter key  then only it is working actually i don't want to press enter key is there any other method ?

Comment: ok i will post a minimal key with this example

Comment: No, you do not have to press anything, the barcode scanners add a return "\n".